# Unable to reuse table name in SQL as constraint still exists

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to rename an empty table with its old name.

I had created constraints in the past (innodb), but that table doesn't exist anymore and if I try to reuse its name (no matter if I create a new table or try to rename another table), I get the following error:

> errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed"

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
2021-07-16 14:50:24 0x2508 Error in foreign key constraint of table database/publisheremails:
there is no index in the table which would contain
the columns as the first columns, or the data types in the
table do not match the ones in the referenced table
or one of the ON ... SET NULL columns is declared NOT NULL. Constraint:
,
  CONSTRAINT `publisheremails_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`agencyid`) REFERENCES `agencies` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

I tried to drop the constraint with this code:

```
ALTER TABLE old_publisheremails
DROP FOREIGN KEY publisheremails_ibfk_1;
```

I get the following error:

> #1091 - Can't DROP FOREIGN KEY `publisheremails_ibfk_1`; check that it exists

I also tried to drop it with the old table name, but I get this error:

> #1146 - Table 'database.publisheremails' doesn't exist

Same goes if I try to drop it from 'agencies'...

Answer (score 0):

Check which foreign keys the table actually has and which name it has with

```
SELECT 
  TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,CONSTRAINT_NAME, REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME,REFERENCED_COLUMN_NAME
FROM
  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE
WHERE
  REFERENCED_TABLE_SCHEMA = '<database>' AND
  REFERENCED_TABLE_NAME = 'old_publisheremails';
```

And you can't drop the publisheremails_ibfk_1 because it **doesn't exist** till now

So check the `agencyid`  column if it has the same data type as agencies `(`id`) and change it

Comment: Thanks, actually, when I run your query, I get zero rows.
The data type for all my IDs (whether they are foreign keys or primary keys) is always INT 11, I double-checked and it is congruent :(

Comment: please add the create tables for both tables ideally in a dbfiddle

Comment: Thanks, nbk, I have decided to make a copy of the database with no constraints, and that I hope has solved the problem.
Fun fact, I cannot rename the problematic database either because of that issue.

I use phpmyadmin, I rarely run queries manually and the tables and constraints were created via phpmyadmin

Comment: instead of ibt(11) use BIGINT  also as you read the error message in it entire you see one of the coklumns is NOT NULL and the other NULL, which doesn't work as you see